# Key error while creating Auto Scaling groups in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm trying to write an Ansible playbook that creates a Launch Template in AWS. For some reason, i'm getting an error of `KeyError: 'launch_config_name'` while creating the Auto Scaling groups. I find it super weird, since i don't have a param of Launch Configuration.

In addition, i see in AWS consul that the new Launch Template is associated is added to the Autoscaling Group, and everything seems to be working properly. What could be the issue?

Ansible core version: 2.12.9

```
- name: create launch template
  community.aws.ec2_launch_template:
    name: "{{ service }}-lt-{{ date.stdout }}"
    state: present
    region:  "{{ region }}"
    image_id: "{{ image_id }}"
    key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
    security_group_ids: "{{ sg }}"
    instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
    iam_instance_profile: "{{ iam_instance_profile }}"

  - name: create auto scaling group
    community.aws.ec2_asg:
      name: "{{ service }}"
      state: present
      region: "{{ region }}"
      load_balancers: "{{  service +'-lb' }}"
      target_group_arns:
        - "{{ service_target_group_arn }}"
      launch_template:
        launch_template_name: "{{ service }}-lt-{{ date.stdout }}"
      health_check_period: "{{ health_check_period }}"
      health_check_type: "{{ health_check_type }}"
      metrics_collection: yes
      replace_all_instances: yes
      replace_batch_size: "{{ max_size|int - desired_capacity|int }}"
      min_size: "{{ min_size }}"
      max_size: "{{ max_size }}"
      desired_capacity: "{{ desired_capacity }}"
      vpc_zone_identifier:
        - "{{ p1 }}"
        - "{{ p2 }}"
      wait_for_instances: true 
      wait_timeout: "{{ wait_timeout }}"
```

Comment: Try experimenting with the `name` fields -- just put some plain text in there to see if that fixes the error, rather than a calculated value. Might be some bad characters in the current name.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I don't think it's a naming issue. This error happens to me when the LC in the ASG is replaced by Launch Template. Also, i get an error, but in AWS consul, everything looks OK.